# Format calendar cells to change colour when an event is added

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps, autofill, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm using Google Spreadsheets to create a calendar that my Admin Team can access and put their names down for certain jobs that need to be done. To make it easier to see, I'm trying to conditionally format the cells so that they change colour when an event is added to that cell. And I have three different cells for each date to format, as I had to break them into the date, the event, and the space where Admins put their names down.

The thing is, I have to do this with *each individual cell*, which is tiresome at the least; I spent an hour last night searching for the formula to do what I wanted, and only managed to do two cells. It takes too long to do this, so I was wondering if there's a way to do this quicker, since dragging doesn't sequence the cells. They'll all change when the original cell has text.

The formulae I'm using are `=LEN(A6)>0` and `=IF(A6>0,true,false)`

Is there a way I can get the cells to sequence, or will I have to do it all manually?

Comment: I'm formatting one cell in three with the `=LEN(A6)>0` and the other two with the IF statement, like I explained. If the middle cell has any text in it, all three cells should change colour to yellow.

Answer (score 0):

Please try selecting ColumnA, Format > Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
=OR(A1<>"",A2<>"",A3<>"")
```

Colour yellow and Range: `A2:A`